# Group values and store indexes of as comma-separated values

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation, grouping

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 9
    [10] => 10
)
```

In the example above there are various duplicate numbers.

I want the output to be as follows:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => 0,1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 5
        [5] => 6
        [6] => 7
        [7] => 8,9
        [8] => 10

    )
```

I would like to be able to create a new array and display the key in the original array as a value in the second one. This means that 0 and 1 share the same value, and  8 and 9 share the same value too.

Update:

I used the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790664/grouping-of-array-in-php) but I wasn't successful in achieving what I wanted as mine is a flat array. The answers I found only referred to multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Create an associative array that uses the values from the original array as the keys, and pushes the keys onto an array in the values. Then at the end you can use `array_values()` to convert the associative array into an indexed array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43594677/2943403

Comment: Whenever you find yourself typing "_StackOverflow is not a free coding service._", this should alert you to the importance of the downvote button and its mouseover text.

Comment: @Barmar - I put this question around 3 am before I slept and after trying to solve the problem for hours by myself and going through similar questions on StackOverflow. I was very tired and I forgot to put what I tried. I've updated my answer. I hope this explains.

Comment: @mickmackusa I tend not to downvote when I'm also voting to close. I see a similar preference expressed in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33291/189777

Comment: @Barmar I downvoted the question because there is no close reason for not providing proof of effort.  I have tried to garner close votes for unattempted questions, but CodyGray has repeatedly informed me that effort is not a question requirement (I dislike this truth). Even if the OP researched, I expect the question to include a best, failed coding attempt in the [mcve] especially for such a small, basic task.  I did not dv the user, I dved the question because I want to discourage future "requirements dump" / "do my work for me" questions.

Comment: @mickmackusa We have been using "Needs more focus" as that close reason for years. I realize that the text of this close reason doesn't really describe it well, but that's how it is.

Comment: @Barmar I know but SOCVR have directly asked me not to request Needs More Focus close votes for very narrow/basic questions that show no effort. They claim that if there are not too many moving parts, then it is not asking too many questions at once.  I hunted for an exact dupe - as you know I do - for a good while, but couldn't find one that I was proud of.

Comment: @mickmackusa I just upvoted https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason  But until something like that is done, we have to make do with the close reasons we have. Questions like this need to be closed, not just downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should organize a middle array I called `$metaArray`:

```
$array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9, 10];
$metaArray = array();  
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    if (!isset($metaArray[$value])) {
        $metaArray[$value] = $key;
    } else {
        $metaArray[$value] .= ",$key";
    }
}
```

And you obtain an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 0,1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [9] => 8,9
    [10] => 10
)
```

In `$metaArray` you've your values as keys and, as values, the keys of the original array associated to that value. Then, if you want to generate the exact output, you should put your elements in your `$results`:

```
$result = array();
foreach( $metaArray as $key => $value ){
  array_push($result, (string)$value);    
}

print_r($result);
```

And you'll obtain the following, where **all of your values are strings** and not a mix of data types:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0,1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8,9
    [8] => 10
)
```

**Alternative solution**: If you don't need to have all data as strings, please use the solution suggested by *mickmausa* to calculate `$result`, so:

```
$result = array_values($metaArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the loop and check if you are processing the first occurrence of a given value.  If so, just push the new keyed element into the result set.  If not, use concatenation to append the new value to the old value at the respective key.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rT9kke))

```
$array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9, 10];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
    if (!isset($result[$value])) {
        $result[$value] = $index;
    } else {
        $result[$value] .= ",$index";
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

*I will be happy to withdraw this answer if someone finds a duplicate for this basic task.

Comment: Hey mickmackusa, your reply does not respect the output expected :) Indexes are different ;)

Comment: I have reindexed the output.  there is no reason to re-loop the result array manually.

Comment: Please do not edit your answer to mirror mine -- that is only wasteful of researchers' time.